# Get Average of Found Numbers in Each File to Two Decimal Places

Tags: bash

I have a script that searches through all files in the directory and pulls the number next to the word `<Overall>`. I want to now get the average of the numbers from each file, and output the filename next to the average to two decimal places. I've gotten most of it to work except displaying the average. I should say I think it works, I'm not sure if it's pulling all of the instances in the file, and I'm definitely not sure if it's finding the average, it's hard to tell without the precision. I'm also sorting by the average at the end. I'm trying to use awk and bc to get the average, there's probably a better method.

**What I have now:**

```
path="/home/Downloads/scores/*"

(for i in $path
do
    echo `basename $i .dat` `grep '<Overall>' < $i |
    head -c 10 | tail -c 1 | awk '{total += $1} END {print total/NR}' | bc`
done) | sort -g -k 2
```

**The output i get is:**

```
John 4
Lucy 4
Matt 5
Sara 5
```

But it shouldn't be an integer and it should be to two decimal places.

Additionally, the files I'm searching through look like this:

```
<Student>John
<Math>2
<English>3
<Overall>5

<Student>Richard
<Math>2
<English>2
<Overall>4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, your script does *not* extract all numbers from each file, but only the first digit of the first number. Consider the following file:

```
<Overall>123 ...
<Overall>4 <Overall>56 ...
<Overall>7.89 ...
<Overall> 0 ...
```

The command `grep '<Overall>' | head -c 10 | tail -c 1` will only extract `1`.

To extract all numbers preceded by `<Overall>` you can use `grep -Eo '<Overall> *[0-9.]*' | grep -o '[0-9.]*'` or (depending on your version) `grep -Po '<Overall>\s*\K[0-9.]*'`.

To compute the average of these numbers you can use your `awk` command or specialized tools like `... | average` (from the package `num-utils`) or `... | datamash mean 1`.

To print numbers with two decimal places (that is `1.00` instead of `1` and `2.35` instead of `2.34567`) you can use `printf`.

```
#! /bin/bash
path=/home/Downloads/scores/
for i in "$path"/*; do
    avg=$(grep -Eo '<Overall> *[0-9.]*' "$file" | grep -o '[0-9.]*' |
          awk '{total += $1} END {print total/NR}')
    printf '%s %.2f\n' "$(basename "$i" .dat)" "$avg"
done |
sort -g -k 2
```

Sorting works only if file names are free of whitespace (like space, tab, newline).

Note that you can swap out the two lines after `avg=$(` with any method mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sed command and retrieve the values to calculate their average with `bc`:

```
# Read the stdin, store the value in an array and perform a bc call
function avg() { mapfile -t l ; IFS=+ bc <<< "scale=2; (${l[*]})/${#l[@]}" ; }

# Browse the .dat files, then display for each file the average
find . -iname "*.dat" |
  while read f
  do
    f=${f##*/} # Remove the dirname
    # Echoes the file basename and a tabulation (no newline)
    echo -en "${f%.dat}\t"
    # Retrieves all the "Overall" values and passes them to our avg function
    sed -E -e 's/<Overall>([0-9]+)/\1/' "$f" | avg
  done
```

Output example:

```
score-2 1.33
score-3 1.33
score-4 1.66
score-5 .66
```

Comment: Hint: Some points are missing. **1.** compute average **2.** print average with two decimal places. Also `ls | while read` is awful. And `ls` has the the *literal* argument `/home/Downloads/scores/*/*.dat` which most likely does not exist and is not what OP wanted.

Comment: The `sed` command only extracts numbers with a decimal point. Pure integers (as given in the sample input) are not extracted.  Also non-matching lines are printed, for instance `<Student>John`, making it hard to do computations on the output.

Answer (score 0):

The pipeline `head -c 10 | tail -c 1 | awk '{total += $1} END {print total/NR}' | bc` needs improvement.

- `head -c 10 | tail -c 1` leaves only the 10th character of the **first** *Overall* line from each file; better drop that.
- Instead, use `awk` to "remove" the prefix `<Overall>` and extract the number; we can do this by using `<Overall>` for the input field separator.
- Also use `awk` to format the result to two decimal places.
- Since `awk` did the job, there's no more need for `bc`; drop it.

The above pipeline becomes `awk -F'<Overall>' '{total += $2} END {printf "%.2f\n", total/NR}'`.
Don't miss to keep the `` ` `` after it.